# DB2 external stored procedure fails with CPF9810 when called from client

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

In a green screen session, caling a program MYLIB/TESTPRG works when my library list is set to QGPL, QTEMP, VENDRLIB1, VENDRLIB2, VENDRLIB3. I can execute `call MYLIB/TESTPRG` on a green screen command line.

I want to be able to run this command from my Windows client. I created an external stored procedure MYLIB/TESTPROC with external name MYLIB/TESTPRG as I have seen in various articles. My original question stated that I could execute this procedure successfully in STRSQL in a green screen session with my library list as above, but that is false. It does not work. It simply says 'Trigger program or external routine detected an error.' Sorry for the wrong information.

When MYLIB/TESTPROC is called from the client (`CALL MYLIB/TESTPROC`), it fails with CPF9810 (Library &1 not found). I connected to the database via i Navigator -> Run SQL Scripts. In Connection -> JDBC Settings I had Default SQL schema = 'Use library list of server job' and set Schema list=QGPL,QTEMP,VENDRLIB1,VENDRLIB2,VENDRLIB3. I then executed `CALL MYLIB/TESTPROC` and got the message as stated above.

What works is when I run the program, i.e. `CALL MYLIB/TESTPRG` on a green screen command line.

TESTPRG is a C program that takes no arguments. The stored procedure was defined like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB/TESTPROC
    LANGUAGE C 
    SPECIFIC MYLIB/TESTPROC 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    NO SQL 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    EXTERNAL NAME 'MYLIB/TESTPRG' 
    PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL ;
```

Comment: In IBM Data Studio, there is a screen where you set the library list. I set it exactly the same as for i Navigator and I get the same error. In both cases I know that the library list is being used because if I remove one of the necessary libraries then the run time error will be that a given object could not be found.

Comment: Note that so far I am not attempting to call the procedure from my own code. I tried the two named query tools, both developed by IBM. Also, my procedure takes no parameters.

Comment: Why not add the library in the call CALL PGM(MYLIB/TESTPROC) ?

Comment: The message does not specify the name of the library that is not found. By the way, TESTPROC is a stored procedure.

Comment: My original question stated that the sproc worked in STRSQL. It doesn't. My problem is that calling a program via an external sproc is not working for me as I have seen in examples. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Did you try call mylib.testproc , typically sql wants the . between library and sproc name instead of the /.

Comment: The result is the same whether I use / or .

Comment: @Douglas Korinke - If I call the *program* directly in the client SQL query window, i.e.,  without the sproc wrapper like this `CALL MYLIB/TESTPRG`  it works as long as the client's library list was set correctly before connecting. I don't need to add anything to the call. I would like to know why it is suggested to create external procedures if they are not necessary, but if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`CPF9810 - Library &1 not found` means that something is trying to access Library `&1` (whatever that is, you didn't tell us) and the library as typed is not on the system anywhere. &1 is not the name of the library, it is a substitution variable which will display the library name in the job log. Look at the real library spelling in the job log. Check your spelling. Check the connection to make sure all the libraries are specified correctly. The message will tell you exactly which library is causing the problem.

If indeed the program works in green screen when the library list is set properly, then I would expect the problem to be in your connection where it is trying to set a library list. You cannot add a non-existent library to the library list. That is why it works in green screen, your library is necessarily typed correctly there, or it wouldn't be in the library list. You would get a similar error (same text, different error code) if you tried to add library with a spelling error to the library list in green screen.

Figure out the full text of the message (look in the job log), and you will see just what is throwing the error, and what the library is. Hint, it is not likely SQL throwing the error as those errors all look like SQL#### or SQ#####. More likely a CL command or it's processing program being called by an IBM server that is sending a CPF message.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, you can directly call simple programs without defining an external SQL procedure based on this documentation from IBM:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcallsta.htm

I believe the recommendation to create your own external procedure definition for simple programs is primarily to reduce ambiguity.  If you have programs and procedures that happen to have matching names, you need to know the rules list to figure out which one is being called for instance.

Also, the rules for external functions are different than external stored procedures and those get confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, I usually make my procedure calls with the library within the call command.

In a terminal session using CALL PGM(MYLIB/TESTPROC). Or in a SQL session using CALL MYLIB.TESTPROC.

This can prevent someone from inadvertently putting your procedure in a personal library or the like. I usually do not specify a session library list on my SQL clients, accepting the system library list.

Answer (score 0):

I had promised to accept Douglas Korinke's comment as an answer. However, I was experimenting a lot and I am no longer sure of what I knew and when I knew it. My problem had something to do with parameter passing to the C program. If I can reproduce it with a simple case I will ask another question.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. I would consider this a comment on your question. If you feel this is "more substantial" than what belongs in the comments section, you should edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

In a Java program it is possible to set the libraries by using the following method :
ds.setLibraries("list of libraries");

Example :

```
ds.setServerName("server1");
ds.setPortNumber(1780);
ds.setDatabaseName("DBTEST");
ds.setLibraries("*LIBL,DAT452BS,DAT452BP");
```